# Deleting a neo4j node along with its relationships through java core API

Tags: java, neo4j

My objective is to delete a node along with all its relationships in a single shot in neo4j graph database.

So far, I have been following this approach,

> - Get all the relationships(BOTH direction) for a node
> - delete the relationships
> - finally delete the node.

Is this the standard approach or anything else available? I don't intend to use Cypher query for this. I want to achieve this through Java core API itself.

Comment: I think this is the only and safe way to delete the nodes with multiple relationship.. not sure if its already present some where in api

Comment: Does this essentially have to be performed inside a single transaction??

Comment: I am not sure, since I used Spring Data Neo4j which manages transactions :) probably Stefen answer is what u r looking for

Answer (score 3):

when using java API the described steps are correct:

```
 try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
     Node node = // my node to delete     
     for (Relationship r : node.getRelationships()) {
         r.delete();
     }
     node.delete();
     tx.success();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks :) But in my case, I will get the relationships for the node in one transaction and delete the node along with its relationships in another transaction. The reason behind this is I am using external lock on the entities before modifying them in the graph database. So for locking the entities during creation/deletion, I need to know the keys. Should I get the keys,lock them and delete them in a single transaction?

Comment: I'd try this in a single transaction just like you've described in your comment.